# Django-viewsets. How to get the ID parameter from the path in perform_create fun

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I'm trying to do a REST in Django using the VIEWSETS library. I created a Container model that works well. Container is associated with the ContainerModerator model. The endpoint should be:

POST containers/{container_id}/moderators

One of the fields in ContainerModerator is container_id. I would like to get it from the path.

Below is what I have now. I tried in different ways to get there. I also read similar posts, usually for a library other than VIEWSETS.
I am a beginner and I wonder if there is a simple, elegant solution for this case that will be easy for me to understand?
Should I use other libraries like APIVIEW or GenericAPIView?

models:

```
class ContainerModerator(models.Model):
  moderator_id = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  container_id = models.ForeignKey(Container, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

serializers:

```
class ContainerModeratorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:
    model = models.ContainerModerator
    fields = '__all__'
```

views:

```
class ContainerModeratorViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  serializer_class = serializers.ContainerModeratorSerializer
  queryset = models.ContainerModerator.objects.all()

  def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save()
```

urls:

```
router.register('v1/containers/<int:container_id>/moderators', 
views.ContainerModeratorViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
  path('', include(router.urls))
]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the container_id from `self.kwargs['container_id']` and search Container instance with container_id.
Particularly  you need something like this in your viewset:

```
class ContainerModeratorViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
     serializer_class = serializers.ContainerModeratorSerializer
     queryset = models.ContainerModerator.objects.all()

     def get_object(self):
         #Override this method to get your cantainer instance
         return get_object_or_404(Container, id=self.kwargs['pk']) 

     def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)):

        instance = self.get_object()
        data = {
           container : instance.id,
           moderator : request.user
        }

        return self.create(data)

    def create(self, data):
       serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)

       self.permform_create(serializer)
       return Response(serializer.data)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
```

Just read the source code of GenericAPIView, ModelViewSet and ViewMixins  carefully  to see how it connect to each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from the simply by using `self.get_object()` method which is available under `RetrieveModelMixin`

Here is the implementation of `RetrieveModelMixin`,

```
def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = self.get_object()
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

> The ModelViewSet class inherits from GenericAPIView and includes implementations for various actions, by mixing in the behavior of the various mixin classes.
>
> The actions provided by the ModelViewSet class are .list(),
>   .retrieve(), .create(), .update(), .partial_update(), and .destroy().

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset